# sequelize alter existing table with "ON DELETE CASCADE"

Tags: sqlite, sequelize.js, cascade, alter

I have **existing** tables with column 'endpointId' with "ON DELETE NO ACTION" and I want to alter column to change this to "ON DELETE CASCADE"
What I have tried is to do:

```
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.sequelize.query("ALTER TABLE `Analyses` ALTER COLUMN `endpointId` INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES `Endpoints` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE");
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.sequelize.query("ALTER TABLE `Analyses` ALTER COLUMN `endpointId` INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES `Endpoints` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE");
  }
};
```

but getting error:

```
ERROR: SQLITE_ERROR: near "ALTER": syntax error
```

It seems I need to remove Constraint first, but I can't find any for the table. Is there a way to check constraint?

```
await queryInterface.removeConstraint('Analyses', '???');
```

Comment: Could it be those backquotes you're using to enclose the table name in?

Comment: shouldn't be, I tested with normal quotes same

Comment: what's your backend SQL database? Some systems might use `modify column` instead of `alter column`

Comment: I'm using "sqlite" and Sequelize to perform changes. Modify perform an error: "ERROR: SQLITE_ERROR: near "MODIFY": syntax error"

Comment: Sqlite does not allow modifying/altering columns. Only `RENAME`, `ADD` and `DROP` are allowed. Here's the doc: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

Comment: owh :( So I will need to drop and create a new column with the new options